# lightbox that can handle php requests

Tags: php, jquery, lightbox

Is it possible for a lightbox to get a get request and just run the php with the values gotten on the clicked link?

Like if I have:

```
<a href='showTrusts.php?siteUrl=$row->siteUrl'>click</a>
```

is it possible to have a lighbox,thickbox, or whatever that will get the clicked url and then the php executes and displays the correct info? I was looking at colorbox but couldn't get the php to load so I started wondering if it was even possible

Comment: HTTP clients don't care what server side processes are involved in generating content, only what the content **is** (HTML document? Image? etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) with iFrame

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#linkId").fancybox({
            'width'             : '80%',
            'height'            : '95%',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'type'              : 'iframe',
            'href'              : 'mypahe.html',
    });
});

<button id="linkId" name="linkId" class="buttonSmall">Show Frame</button>
```

Comment: ok, got the fancybox working (thanks) but if I click on it instead of having it open the fancybox it just sends me to that URL. I already added the css and js required and checked the "how to use" but as far as I can see it's corect =/

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use only `PHP` to access the data, as it will refresh the page and the lightbox will close. What you are going to need to do is use `AJAX` and pass some data into a `PHP` script.

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery's "dialogue" recently for a php app - worth looking at, http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/